# optimal k value based on intertia

Tags: python, k-means

If this is a duplicate let me know, but I haven't found graphs with derivative here. Here is my elbow curve [ red is its 2-nd derivative]. I am looking for optimal k value for k-means algorithm.

Should it be 6 or 10?

[image]

Comment: The "elbow" cannot always be unambiguously identified, especially in your case. Without any context knowledge I'd say 10 in your case, but it depends on more than just the inertia value. Choosing the right value of `k` also depends on e.g. your goal: often, a lower value of `k` is more desirable since it will give more clear results, even though choosing more clusters will give better results (i.e. a better separation of your items).

Comment: I want to perform k means on RGB image